# Centering a page-width background-image is stretching the page

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours, and I've searched across the whole internet with no luck.

I'm trying to centre this background image in the page; however as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m2oy2wmw/1/) by using this method it stretches the width of the page, meaning that you can scroll past the width of the page.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="bground">d</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
}

div.bground {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: -50%;
    background: url('http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wpcontent/uploads/2015/04/skyrim.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
}
```

Comment: Why not just put the bg image on the body? That's a very odd way of going about it.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work

Comment: Really? It should - https://jsfiddle.net/cgnonj0t/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have been moving container div for 50% to the right, that's why you got horizontal scroll-bar, not out of image but out of a div positioning.
Try out this css:

```
div.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
div.bground {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: url('http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/skyrim.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
}
```

Comment: [Codepen sample](http://codepen.io/zlajaa1/pen/XbmEvR) so this is not what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/m2oy2wmw/3/

I made you a fiddle, if this is what you are looking for.

You can always use "100vh" to have full height (even when resizing screen).

```css
div.container {
    height: 100vh; //100vh to always have 100% height.
    width: 100%;
    background: url('http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/skyrim.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="bground">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then what are you trying to do?
If you look at the fiddle it works?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you need, let me know what is not working for you...

```css
body {
    background-image: url('http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/skyrim.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  </body>
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.